# Selfadjoint and continuous operator on a complex Hilbert space

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $T\colon H\to H$ be a selfadjoint continuous operator on a complex Hilbert space. Show:

$$
\lVert (T\pm i\mbox{Id})x\rVert^2=\lVert Tx\rVert^2+\lVert x\rVert^2~\forall~x\in H.
$$

--

How can I show that?

I started with
$$
\lVert (T\pm i\mbox{Id})x\rVert^2=\langle Tx\pm ix,Tx\pm ix\rangle.
$$

Comment: Hint: Try using the bilinearity (technically, sesquilinearity) of the inner product.

Comment: Don't forget that pulling constants things out of the second slot makes them complex conjugates.

Comment: Okay, then I get $\langle Tx,Tx\rangle\pm\langle ix,Tx\rangle\pm\langle Tx,ix\rangle\pm\langle ix,ix\rangle=\langle Tx,Tx\rangle\pm i\langle x,Tx\rangle\pm\overline{i}\langle Tx,x\rangle\pm i^2\langle x,x\rangle$. But what then?

Comment: Pull the $i$'s out of the inner products, but pay attention to the comment from @ZachL.

Comment: $\langle Tx,Tx\rangle\pm i \langle x,Tx\rangle\mp i \langle Tx,x\rangle\pm \langle x,x\rangle$

Comment: Okay, I did, see my last comment. I edited it.

Comment: Please continue yourself. Is it clear, that $\bar i=-i$? And, the other one is $\bar i i=?$ instead of $i^2$. You will also need that $T$ is selfadjoint, $T^*=T$, or more usefully now, $\langle Tu,v\rangle=\langle u,Tv\rangle$ for any $u,v$.

Comment: I will try by myself later. Would be great if you could have a look on it then. With regards, math12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$\| T(x) + ix\|^2 = \|T(x)\|^2 + \|x\|^2 + \langle T(x), ix\rangle + \langle
ix, T(x)\rangle = \|T(x)\|^2 + \|x\|^2 - i\langle T(x), x\rangle +  i \langle x, T(x)\rangle$$

Now we know that $\langle x, T(x)\rangle = \langle T(x), x\rangle$, so our conclusion follows forthwith.